# Higher order Leibniz rule and ordered multiindex notation

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations, notation

Although I think this is probably known, I am making here a short exposition on the multiindex notations I am using to make this question self-contained. I note that there is at least two different multiindex notations used in the calculus of variations/jet spaces literature, and this question is somewhat about the connection between the two. As far as I am aware, there is no widespread names for these notations so I am going to call them *ordered multiindex notation* and *combinatorial multiindex notation*.

I am going to work on an open set $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ of the $n$ dimensional real coordinate space, i.e. I work with "$n$ variables", and the latin indices $i,j,k,...$ take the values $1,...,n$. A generic point of $X$ is denoted $x=(x^1,...,x^n)=(x^i)_{i=1}^n$.

**Ordered multiindex notation:**

Let $\mathbb N_n=\{1,...,n\}$. An ordered multiindex of length $r$ is an element of $$ \mathbb N^r_n=\mathbb N_n\times...\times\mathbb N_n,\quad(r\text{ times}), $$written as $I=(i_1,...,i_r)$. The length is written as $|I|=r$.

If $S_r$ is the group of permutations of $\mathbb N_r$, then $S_r$ acts naturally on $\mathbb N^r_n$ by $\sigma\cdot I=(i_{\sigma(1)},...,i_{\sigma(r)})$. The orbit of this group action that passes through $I\in\mathbb N^r_n$ is denoted $[I]$, and the space of orbits is denoted $$ [\mathbb N^r_n]=\mathbb N^r_n/S_r. $$ That is, $[I]$ is the equivalence class consisting of all ordered multiindices of length $|I|=r$ that differ from $I$ by permutations. Let us also call elements of $[\mathbb N^r_n]$ *permutation classes*.

An ordered multiindex $I=(i_1,...,i_r)$ is *nondecreasing* if $i_1\le ...\le i_r$. Clearly each permutation class $[I]$ contains exactly one nondecreasing multiindex, therefore the class $[I]$ may be identified with the nondecreasing rearrangement of $I$. To denote this operation explicitly, let $\{I\}$ be the nondecreasing rearrangement of $I$, and when an array, say $S_{i_1...i_r}$, is considered, write $S_{\{i_1...i_r\}}$ for the nondecreasing rearrangement.

Let $\mathrm{card}(S)$ denote the cardinality of the set $S$, then we have $$ \mathrm{card}([I])=N(I)=N(i_1,...,i_r)=\frac{r!}{n_1!...n_n!}, $$ where $r=|I|$ and $n_i$ is the number of times the index $i$ appears in $I$.

Suppose that $S_{i_1...i_r}$ and $T^{i_1...i_r}$ are two completely symmetric arrays. Then $$ \sum_{i_1\le...\le i_r}S_{i_1...i_r}T^{i_1...i_r}=\sum_{i_1...i_r}\frac{1}{N(I)}S_{i_1...i_r}T^{i_1...i_r}. $$

Given two ordered multiindices $I\in\mathbb N^r_n$ and $J\in\mathbb N^s_n$, their *concatenation* is $IJ=(i_1,...,i_r,j_1,...,j_s)$.

**Combinatorial multiindex notation:**

Working on the same coordinate space with $n$ variables, a combinatorial multiindex is an element of$$\mathbb N^n=\mathbb N\times...\times\mathbb N\quad(n\text{ times}),$$that is an ordered list of $n$ natural numbers ($0$ included). A generic combinatorial multiindex will be written as $$ A=(a_1,...,a_n). $$

The usual operations are:

- Length: $|A|=a_1+...+a_n$.
- Factorial: $A!=a_1!...a_n!$.
- Partial order: $A\le B$ if and only if $a_i\le b_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$.
- Sum and difference: $A+B=(a_1+b_1,...,a_n+b_n)$, $A-B=(a_1-b_1,...,a_n-b_n)$ (only defined if $B\le A$).
- Binomial coefficient: $$\left(\begin{matrix} A \\ B\end{matrix}\right)=\frac{A!}{B!(A-B)!} $$(for $B\le A$).

**Relationships between the two:**

There is a bijective correspondance between combinatorial multiindices and permutation classes of (alternatively, nondecreasing) ordered multiindices. Given an ordered multiindex $I=(i_1,...,i_r)$, let $a_i$ be the number of times $i$ appears in $I$, then the corresponding combinatorial multiindex is $A=(a_1,...,a_n)$. Conversely, given $A=(a_1,...,a_n)$, the corresponding permutation class of ordered multiindices is the class of $I=(1,...,1,2,...,2,...,n,...,n)$ with the $1$s appearing $a_1$ times, the $2$s appearing $a_2$ times, etc.

Under this correspondance,

- the length of $I$ is the length of $A$;
- the concatenation $IJ$ of $I$ and $J$ is the sum $A+B$ (if $A$ corresponds to $I$ and $B$ corresponds to $J$);
- we have $$ N(I)=\frac{|A|!}{A!}=\frac{|I|!}{A!}, $$whenever $A$ corresponds to $I$.

If $S_{i_1...i_r}$ is a totally symmetric array, it may be indexed with combinatorial multiindices as well with $S_A$ (for $|A|=r$) being $S_I=S_{i_1,...,i_r}$, whenever $I$ corresponds to $A$, and we also have $$ \sum_{|A|=r}S_AT^A=\sum_{i_1\le...\le i_r}S_I T^I. $$

**Higher order Leibniz rule:**

Given two functions $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that are sufficiently differentiable, and defining $$ \partial^A=\frac{\partial^{|A|}}{\partial(x^1)^{a_1}...\partial(x^n)^{a_n}}, $$ the higher-order Leibniz rule is $$ \partial^A(fg)=\sum_{B+C=A}\frac{A!}{B!C!}(\partial^B f)(\partial^C g). $$

**Higher order Leibniz rule with ordered multiindices:**

I'd like to rewrite the higher order Leibniz rule with ordered multiindices instead of combinatorial multiindices. For any ordered multiindex $I=(i_1,...,i_r)$, let $\partial_I=\partial_{i_1},...,\partial_{i_r}$ denote the iterated partial derivatives.

I have made some progress:

*Step 1*: Using the above correspondances, we may rewrite the higher order Leibniz rule as $$ \partial_I(fg)=\sum_{J,K}^\ast\frac{|I|!}{|J|!|K|!}\frac{N(J)N(K)}{N(I)}(\partial_J f)(\partial_K g), $$ where $I$ is the *nondecreasing* ordered multiindex that corresponds to $A$, the asterisk ($\ast$) over the sum means that 1) $J$ and $K$ are nondrecreasing, 2) $\{JK\}=I$, i.e. the concatenation of $J$ and $K$ when rearranged to nondecreasing order must be $I$.

To derive this, I have used that to each combinatorial multiindex corresponds a unique nondecreasing ordered multiindex, and that summing over symmetric arrays indexed by conbinatorial multiindices is equivalent to summing over symmetric arrays with nondecreasing ordered multiindices, and I have also used $$ A!=\frac{|I|!}{N(I)}, $$ where $I$ corresponds to $A$.

*Step 2*: We can get rid of condition 1) as follows. The class $[J]$ of $J$ has exactly $N(J)$ elements, thus we can write $$ \partial_I(fg)=\frac{1}{N(I)}\sum_{J,K}^{\{JK\}=I}\frac{|I|!}{|J|!|K|!}(\partial_J f)(\partial_K g), $$with the factors of $N(J)N(K)$ disappearing from the expression because now we sum over all pairs $J,K$ of ordered multiindices that satisfy $\{JK\}=I$, not just over the nondecreasing ones.

*Step 3*: The left hand side is manifestly symmetric, so we may write $$ \partial_I(fg)=\frac{1}{N(I)}\sum_{J,K}^{[JK]=[I]}\frac{|I|!}{|J|!|K|!}(\partial_J f)(\partial_K g), $$ where now $I$ may be arbitrarily ordered.

**Questions:**

The problem is that this formula is wrong. At least the factor of $1/N(I)$ should not be there. I suspect the formula is right aside from that. However I think the steps I have taken are sound and I don't see where it all went wrong. So...

- What is the correct way to write the higher-order Leibniz rule in ordered multiindex notation? What am I doing wrong?
- The formula involves a rather unusual summation that does not fit well into the framework of classical tensor calculus. Is there some neat way to write it in a way that may be conveniently used with the usual tensor calculus index notation?

Comment: The correct thing is to sum over all subsequences of $I$, which can be easily proven from the ordinary Leibniz rule by induction. I don't quite see the error but I think all this stuff about concatenating and rearranging things obscures the combinatorics.

Comment: @lambda Well I first tried to prove it directly like that, but encountered some blocks. Then I took Saunders' proof via combinatorial multiindices and decided to try to convert that to ordered multiindices. To be honest, I am not very proficient with combinatorics.